# Sign in with email and password. How to find out which of them both was wrong when failed?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When the Login process failed, I would like to find out what went wrong. So if the email was wrong or the password. So I can send more detailed instructions to go on with the process.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        emailView = findViewById(R.id.emailText);
        passwordView = findViewById(R.id.pwText);

        loginB = findViewById(R.id.loginB);
        registerB = findViewById(R.id.registerB);

        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        loginB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = emailView.getText().toString();
                String password = passwordView.getText().toString();

                if(email.isEmpty()){
                    emailView.setError("Please enter a valid Email");
                    emailView.requestFocus();
                }
                if(password.isEmpty()){
                    passwordView.setError("Please enter a passoword");
                }
                if(!(email.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty())){
                    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }else{
                                //My Question
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        registerB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Tried to find a function in task which could help but didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, you don't usually tell *what* was wrong with the credentials.

If you tell "username not valid" and "password not valid", an attacker can use that to determine which usernames exist. It's a bit of security by obscurity, but legitimate users would know their username (or their email address at least, to retrieve the credentials).

Answer (score 0):

@Kayaman's answer is correct: for security reasons you can't determine which part of the credentials was incorrect. But for a better user experience you can do a bit more...

If you want to know if an email address is registered, you can call [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(java.lang.String)). You can use that to determine if the email is of a known Firebase user, and in that case for example offer to [send a password reset email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#sendPasswordResetEmail(java.lang.String)).